# Typescript: how do you define a union type with boolean or a callback function?

Tags: javascript, typescript

How do you set a union type for a callback function or boolean? I tried this, but I got:

```
export interface IActions {
  dragend?: ((m:any)=>void) | boolean;
  click?:  ((m:any)=>void) | boolean;
  dblclick?:  ((m:any)=>void) | boolean;
}


    // using the following type guard in code
    // also tried `this.setting.click instanceof Function`
    if (typeof this.setting.click != 'boolean'){
      this.setting.click(m);
    } else {
      // default action
    }
```

Error:

> error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'boolean | ((m: any) => void)' has no compatible call signatures.

Comment: What are your compiler settings, without strictnullchecks your code works, with strict null checks I get a different error then yours.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) to create if statements that automatically type variables for you.

One way to write these guards would be:

(Forgive the naming ... I'm not feeling terribly creative today!)

```
type Action = (m: any) => void;
type ActionOrBoolean = Action | boolean;

function isActionOrBooleanAction(actionOrBoolean: ActionOrBoolean): actionOrBoolean is Action {
    return typeof actionOrBoolean != 'boolean';
}

function isActionOrBooleanBoolean(actionOrBoolean: ActionOrBoolean): actionOrBoolean is boolean {
    return typeof actionOrBoolean == 'boolean';
}
```

And they can be used like:

```
let v3: ActionOrBoolean = (Math.random() > 0.5)
  ? (p1: any) => {}
  : true;

if(isActionOrBooleanBoolean(v3)) {
    v3 = false;
} else if(isActionOrBooleanAction(v3)) {
    v3("");
}
```

Finally, here's a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p8yL0a2n/1/) showing it all working.

```
writeLine("v1: " + v1);
writeLine("v1 isActionOrBooleanAction: " + isActionOrBooleanAction(v1));
writeLine("v1 isActionOrBooleanBoolean: " + isActionOrBooleanBoolean(v1));

writeLine("v2: " + v2);
writeLine("v2 isActionOrBooleanAction: " + isActionOrBooleanAction(v2));
writeLine("v2 isActionOrBooleanBoolean: " + isActionOrBooleanBoolean(v2));

// Example
let v3: ActionOrBoolean = (Math.random() > 0.5)
  ? (p1: any) => {}
  : true;

if(isActionOrBooleanBoolean(v3)) {
    v3 = false;
} else if(isActionOrBooleanAction(v3)) {
    v3("");
}
```

Output:

> v1: true
>
> v1 isActionOrBooleanAction: false
>
> v1 isActionOrBooleanBoolean: true
>
> v2: function (p1) { }
>
> v2 isActionOrBooleanAction: true
>
> v2 isActionOrBooleanBoolean: false